# Could not find function colMedians

Tags: r

I have seen [this](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/robustbase/versions/0.92-6/topics/colMedians), and I have added the package  `MatrixStats`.

But when I run the code

```
colMeans(adult_csv[5], na.rm = TRUE)
colMedians(adult_csv[5], na.rm = TRUE)
```

it passes the first line, but complains with `colMedians` with:

> R: could not find function colMedians

Comment: You need the package miscTools

Comment: Did you do: library("matrixStats") first?

Comment: According to your link, the package is 
`robustbase`. Just installed it and there is the function.

Comment: @wligtenberg no, but the package is installed

Comment: @user5363938 when you want to use a function from an R package you first have to make it available by calling library("packageName") first.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`colMeans()` is in `base` and `colMedians` is in the `matrixStats` package.

```
find("colMedians")
#  [1] "package:matrixStats"
find("colMeans")
#  [1] "package:base"
```

Attach the package first:

```
library(matrixStats)
colMeans(adult_csv[5], na.rm = TRUE)
colMedians(adult_csv[5], na.rm = TRUE)
```

Comment: what happens when you type `find("colMedians")` in the console?

Comment: You should be able to get output using `matrixStats::colMedians(matrix(rnorm(100), ncol=10))`. What does this produce for you?

Comment: Sounds like it is functioning just fine. 
Are you passing `colMedians()` a data frame? It is expecting a matrix.
We need more information on the `adult_csv` object.

Comment: i am passing a column of my data set

Comment: For a single column, you can just use `median()`. You do not need a column-wise operation for a single vector